# Loading StringGrid from text file

Tags: delphi, load, numbers, tstringgrid

How can I load text file with integer numbers separated with space to StringGrid? Each number to each cell. Grid has to be a rectangle, so if some number is missing it should be filled with 0.

Here's what I did so far, but it need to have already set row and column count.

```
  while not eof(f) do
  begin
    while not eoln(f) do
    begin
      read(f, data);
      StringGrid1.Cells[p, l] := data;
      inc(p);
    end;
    p := 0;
    readln(f);
    inc(l);
  end;
```

Comment: Why are you using Pascal IO? Why don't you just load the file into a string list and use the [`SplitString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StrUtils.SplitString) function to split each line?

Comment: Ignore **NO PASCAL I/O** gang, it is fine for this task. Your problem statement is not consistent, how would you determine the positions if more than one consecutive numbers are missing?

Comment: @user539484 Pure venom and spite. Not classy.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would elect not to use Pascal IO here. If you want your code to be able to read Unicode data then Pascal IO cannot help you.

You can do what you describe using a string list to load the file and then `SplitString` from the `StrUtils` unit to parse the string.

```
procedure PopulateStringGrid(Grid: TStringGrid; const FileName: string);
var
  Strings: TStringList;
  Row, Col: Integer;
  Items: TStringDynArray;
begin
  Grid.RowCount := 0;//clear any previous data
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strings.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    Grid.RowCount := Strings.Count;
    for Row := 0 to Strings.Count-1 do
    begin
      Items := SplitString(Strings[Row], ' ');
      for Col := 0 to Grid.ColCount-1 do
        if Col<Length(Items) then
          Grid.Cells[Col, Row] := Items[Col]
        else
          Grid.Cells[Col, Row] := '0';
    end;
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Note that `SplitString` may not be precisely what you need. For example it does not coalesce repeated delimiters into one. To see what I mean consider the following input:

```
Hello    World
```

There are 4 spaces between the two words and `SplitString` would return the following array:

```
'Hello'
''
''
''
'World'
```

If you wish to treat consecutive delimiters as being just one delimiter then you can use the `DelimitedText` property of a string list:

```
procedure PopulateStringGrid(Grid: TStringGrid; const FileName: string);
var
  TextFile, Line: TStringList;
  Row: Integer;
begin
  Grid.RowCount := 0;//clear any previous data
  TextFile := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Line := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Line.Delimiter := ' ';
      TextFile.LoadFromFile(FileName);
      Grid.RowCount := TextFile.Count;
      for Row := 0 to TextFile.Count-1 do
      begin
        Line.DelimitedText := TextFile[Row];
        for Col := 0 to Grid.ColCount-1 do
          if Col<Line.Count then
            Grid.Cells[Col, Row] := Line[Col]
          else
            Grid.Cells[Col, Row] := '0';
      end;
    finally
      Line.Free;
    end;
  finally
    TextFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to give a try to this code.
It's basic but I'm sure with a twist you can solve your problem.

```
procedure LoadFile(FileName: string; StringGrid: TStringGrid);
var
  temp, fName, sName, eMail: string;
  sgItem: TStringList;
  f: textfile;
begin
  assignfile(f, FileName);
  reset(f);
  sgItem := TStringList.Create;
  StringGrid.RowCount := 2;
  while not eof(f) do
  begin
    readln(f, temp);
    fName := copy(temp, 1, pos('|', temp) - 1);
    delete(temp, 1, pos('|', temp));
    sName := copy(temp, 1, pos('|', temp) - 1);
    delete(temp, 1, pos('|', temp));
    eMail := temp;
    sgItem.Clear;
    sgItem.Add(fName);
    sgItem.Add(sName);
    sgItem.Add(eMail);
    StringGrid.Rows[StringGrid.RowCount - 1].AddStrings(sgItem);
    StringGrid.RowCount := StringGrid.RowCount + 1;
  end;
  sgItem.Free;
  closefile(f);
end;
```

Usage :

```
LoadFile('File.txt', StringGrid1);
```

Beny

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    procedure FillStringgrid;
        // Split the line of text into individual entries
        procedure Split(const Delimiter: Char;Input: string;const Strings:TStrings);
        begin
            Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
            Strings.Clear;
            Strings.Delimiter := Delimiter;
            Strings.DelimitedText := Input;
        end;
    var
      strlst  : Tstringlist;
      myfile  : TextFile;
      search  : string;
      i,j     : integer;
    begin
      i:= 0;
      AssignFile(myfile,'filepath');   // specify your file path here
      Reset(myFile);
      while not eof(myfile) do
      begin
          Readln(myfile,search);
          strlst:= Tstringlist.Create;
          Split(' ',search,strlst);    // get the no's separated by the delimiter  
          //adjust your column count based on no of entries
          if StringGrid1.ColCount < strlst.Count then
             StringGrid1.ColCount := strlst.Count;
          StringGrid1.Rows[i]:=strlst; // adjust the row count
          Inc(i);
          StringGrid1.RowCount := i;
      end;
      // free stringlist and textfile      
      CloseFile(myfile) ;
      strlst .free;

      // fill in the blank entries with 0
      for i := 0 to StringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
        begin
        for j := 0 to StringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
          begin
          if StringGrid1.Cells[j,i]='' then
            StringGrid1.Cells[j,i]:='0';
          end;
        end; 
    end;
```